# Government came and took my baby!

Tags: the-sims-2

Okay, so I *may* have left the sim Child unattended for a few hours without calling a babysitter.  All was fine and they even did their homework but then Social Services turned up and stole the child!  At least I'm *hoping* it was Social Services, it was quite a non-descript brown van.

**Is there any way to get back a child taken into custody by Social Services in The Sims 2?**

I tried phoning the adoption service but they declined as I'd already had a child taken away.

Comment: You sick monster.

Comment: Should we migrate this to parenting.se?

Comment: Unlike the real world, the Sims has minimum standards for parenting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to get your child back once it was taken away by the social worker. Your child will be available for adoption by *other* families, but any Sim which has the "Child taken away" memory will never be able to adopt a child.

To avoid this happening in the future, here is when the social worker will take your child away:

- When the child's needs are too low;
- When a child has an F in school;
- When a child is left home alone;
- When a child is too hot or too cold (only with the Seasons expansion pack).

A social worker can take away a baby, a toddler or a child, and will take away all children below teenager level in one visit.

The only way to stop a social worker from taking a child away is to use the "Plead with social worker" interaction, which is only available if you have the Free Time expansion pack, via a lifetime aspiration benefit. The social worker has the ability to teleport the children, so shielding them doesn't work.

Comment: Wow. Thats pretty wack. Such a thing would annoy the crap outta me. I'm not a major sims player, but any game where the govt can take my kid and I have no option of any kind to get him back would piss me off to no end.

Comment: @Ender The court system is to determine whether someone actually did the deed.  The game knows you did the deed, any sort of trial would be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this might work (never did it, though):

1. Develop romantic relationship with some other Sim, preferably made by you so it is sure he doesn't have the memory 'My child taken from me',
2. Propose him to move in. Now you have him in your household.
3. This new sim (!) calls adoption service abd chooses the age group the taken away child was in.
4. Adoption service should allow him to adopt (regardless it's the same household they took the child from). This is memory what matters.
5. The child should be a right one, provided you choose right age group, not a randomly generated someone.
6. Child's memory will be erased & there'lk be some changes in the family tree, but effectively is back.

Make sure not to mess with social service until the child is a teenager. So that this won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure wherever you're talking about the sims 2 on pc or not but there might be cheats you could use to add the child back into your household if you see them again and maybe next time you can delete the social worker before the government take your baby.